# Make a text file read only

Tags: delphi

I'm creating a textfile that will be stored on the desktop of the computer. I want to make this textfile to only be readable so that no one can change its contents.

```
procedure TForm1.Label5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyText: TStringlist;
begin
  MyText := TStringlist.create;
  try
    MyText.Add('H');
    MyText.SaveToFile(Path+'Recipte.txt');
    FileMode := fmOpenRead;
  finally
    MyText.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `FileMode` can't be used the way you're trying to use it, because it has nothing to do with a stringlist, and anyway setting the value only affects the file when used just before opening it, not after it's been written out.

Comment: @KenWhite is right. Also, I suspect `'Path+Recipte.txt'` is an error, too. `Path+Recipte.txt` is a very unusual file name. In addition, one should always use absolute paths (even if they typically are obtained dynamically). Maybe you mean `Path + 'Recipte.txt'`? Anyhow, I am very pleased to see that you use the `try..finally` construct correctly! That's exactly how it should be used! :)

Comment: It's trivial to change the contents of a read only file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TStringList.SaveToFile()` creates a writable file (otherwise it could not write to the file).  You will need to use the Win32 [`SetFileAttributes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfileattributesw) function (or the RTL's [`FileSetAttr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FileSetAttr) wrapper) to set the file as read-only *after* the file has been closed, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Label5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyText: TStringList;
  FileName: string;
begin
  FileName := Path + 'Recipte.txt';
  MyText := TStringList.Create;
  try
    MyText.Add('H');
    MyText.SaveToFile(FileName);
  finally
    MyText.Free;
  end;

  SetFileAttributes(PChar(FileName), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY);
  { or:
  FileSetAttr(FileName, faReadOnly);
  }
end;
```

Comment: @Umsugi most file editing apps don't monitor a file's attributes for changes in real-time, especially the read-only attribute. The OS still knows the file is read-only when needed, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in preventing users from modifying your file just during the execution of your application then you should use `TFileStream` for opening file as it allows you to lock the access to that file for the duration it is opened with by your application.

The code bellow makes use of `TFileStream` to open file with writing capability and locks access to that file to make it only readable by other applications.
If needed you can replace last parameter with `fmShareExclusive` which would prevent any other application of even reading your file during the time it is open by your application.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyText: TStringlist;
  FS: TFileStream;
begin
  MyText := TStringlist.create;
  FS := TFileStream.Create('D:\Test.txt', fmOpenWrite, fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    MyText.Add('H');
    MyText.SaveToStream(FS);
  finally
    FS.Free;
    MyText.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

As for preventing your users from modifying the contents of your file even at times when your application is not running. Well that is much harder. Sure you could change the file attribute to be ReadOnly but your users can change those attributes whenever they want.

One way to prevent your users from modifying your file would be to write it in binary format that can't be easily read and thus also written by humans. Or perhaps you might also consider encoding it.

Another way would be to save the mentioned file to a different location so the user can't find that file so easily. On this note why are you even saving your file to desktop location?

Comment: Highly likely that this code will leak MyText on occasion

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Care to explain why?

Comment: When `TFileStream.Create` raises an exception

Answer (score -1):

Make it a resource. That way the file doesn't need to be written to disk.

Comment: So where would it be persisted, if not on disk?

Comment: Given a requirement to write the file to the desktop, this answer seems a little incongruous